# How to get value from different table based on different join table condition

Tags: mysql, join, left-join

I have three tables.

1. customer - name,email
2. history - id,customer_id,attendee_id,date
3. attendee - name,email

I am trying to fetch the name and email using history table, if the customer_id is -1 then need to get the name and email from the attendee table else from customer table like this :

```
SELECT  * FROM history

left JOIN attendee ON attendee.id  = history.attendee_id AND history.customer_id= '-1'

left JOIN customer ON customer.id = history.customer_id AND history.customer_id != '-1'

WHERE history.id = '605';
```

I can do the same using union all but not using join

the union all code as below

```
select cus.name,cus.email from histroy
join customer cus on cus.id = history.customer_id and history.customer_id not in ('0','-1')
union all
select cus.name,cus.email from history
join attendee cus on cus.id = history.attendee_id and history.attendee_id not in ('0','-1')
```

can i write above code using join.

Comment: A Primarykey should alway be unique and I wouldn't feel quiet comfortable, knowing that there be entries with a value of -1 ... But maybe try a `UNION` join and fetch the results in your frontend.

Comment: union is working fine but i try to case when then is join case with different table on different column

Comment: @Cataklysim can you help me the same union all in join case.